# .NET scheduler class architecture

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, scheduled-tasks

We are developing a custom scheduler class, that should be able to invoke tasks periodically.

We are thinking of two possible approaches:

1. For each task, that has period of X seconds, create its own timer with interval equal to task's period, or
2. Create one timer, and on each its tick recalculate its interval, iterating all tasks and finding one that is the most close in time?

The first approach seems to be more simple and straightforward, but I do not know if creating of 10 or 20 timers is expensive.

How do you think, which one is better from the performance point of view?

Comment: How many tasks are we talking about, and do you want them to be able to run concurrently? (Your second approach wouldn't allow that.)

Comment: Well, we are speaking about some poor tens of tasks. Tasks should be able to run concurrently. When timer's callback executes for a long time, that is bigger than timer interval, will next timer tick occur?

Comment: I have implemented different ways behind an interface IScheduler. In some cases a simple timer that checks for tasks every X ms is good enough.

Comment: @MikhailBrinchuk: That depends on the type of timer you're talking about. Do you *want* the same callback to execute multiple times concurrently, if it takes a long time?

Comment: I thought about `System.Threading.Timer`, and I do want callback to execute multiple times concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

What about using an existing scheduling library like Quartz.net?

> Quartz.NET is a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that
>   can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems.
>   Quartz.NET is a pure .NET library written in C# and is a port of very
>   propular open source Java job scheduling framework, Quartz     . This
>   project owes very much to original Java project, it's father James
>   House and the project contributors.

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I *suspect* that in this case the requirements are simple enough that one of the Timer classes in the BCL is good enough.

Comment: I thought about using this library, but our scheduler is written not by me, and this other person wants to implement it entirely himself.